# Imgproc.FindContours return empty contours

Tags: c#, android, opencv, xamarin

I use OpenCV 2.4.11 for Xamarin.Android with OpenCvBinding. I'm trying to find the largest color area in image.

```
static public Tuple<Bitmap,double> GetArea(Bitmap srcBitmap)
    {
        Mat mat = new Mat(); 
        Mat gray = new Mat();
        Mat mat2 = new Mat();
        double max = 0;
        Mat Hierarchy = new Mat();
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new List<MatOfPoint>();
        Utils.BitmapToMat(srcBitmap, mat);

        Imgproc.CvtColor(mat, gray, Imgproc.ColorRgba2gray);
        Imgproc.AdaptiveThreshold(gray, mat2, 255, Imgproc.AdaptiveThreshGaussianC, Imgproc.ThreshBinaryInv,1111,0);       
        Imgproc.FindContours(mat2, contours, Hierarchy, Imgproc.RetrTree, Imgproc.ChainApproxSimple);

        foreach (MatOfPoint contour in contours)
        {     // never goes here
            if (max < Imgproc.ContourArea(contour)) max = Imgproc.ContourArea(contour);
        }
        Utils.MatToBitmap(mat2,srcBitmap);

        return new Tuple<Bitmap, double>(srcBitmap,max);
    }
```

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO0cO.jpg)

If I comment the line with FindContours, I'll get an excellent picture for searching contours.

[Threshholded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q87Gw.png)

FindContours returns correct image(Reputation doesn't allow to add another link), but(!!) list of contours standing empty. So i can't get the area of these contures.
I would be glad of any help. Thanks!

Comment: [Looks not very fine, but shows that contours in picture shows correctly.](http://imgur.com/Mi0qIXw)

Comment: I can't test it, but you do have a styling error with hierarchy being uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use IList contours = new JavaList();

Comment: Could you add some explenation to this pease?